# Cocoapods, Swift and FMDB Cipher - are these three currently compatible?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, fmdb

There have been some issues with cocoapods/swift/fmdb as outlined [here](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/issues/309#issuecomment-100977714).

Thus as I have decided to encrypt my database, if I add the pod 'FMDB/SQLCipher' to my swift project are there any issues I should know about in advance?.. Will everything work if I just drag the FMDatabaseAdditionsVariadic.swift in manually?

Comment: It has been deleted. Thanks for getting back to me.

Answer (score 0):

1.Installed FMDB using cocoapods.

2.Created a bridging header for FMDB.

```
#import "FMDB.h" // In yourProjectName-Bridging-Header.h
```

3.Add `import FMDB.h`  to your swift file which need to use FMDB.